# Algorithm to create cartesian mesh of 2d concave polygon

Tags: python, algorithm, polygon, mesh

I have a 2d concave polygon with n holes where each of theses holes can contain another m polygons.
Are there any (preferably easy) Algorithms to create a cartesian mesh (mesh of rectangles) of this polygon?

Or are there any python libraries that can already do that?